# Calculating LT50 using dose.p from GLM with two factors

Tags: r, glm

I've been doing analysis on data where `Alive` or `Dead` represents the number of animals surviving after a set `Time` at stressful conditions.

Eg.

```
      Trial Time Alive Dead
1      1  0.0   100    0
2      1  2.0     0   10
3      1  6.0     0   12
4      1  9.0     0   10
5      1 12.0     0   10
6      2  0.0   100    0
7      2  0.5    10    0
8      2  1.0    10    0
9      2  1.5    10    0
10     2  2.0     8    2
11     3  0.0   100    0
12     3  0.5    10    0
13     3  1.0    10    0
14     3  1.5    10    0
15     3  2.0     9    1
16     3  2.5     7    1
17     3  3.0     2    9
18     3  3.5     3    5
```

Using glm and the `dose.p` function from `MASS` I've been able to calculate LT50 with other data sets that seem to match the plotted curve but I am having problems with these particular data for some reason.

```
Time=c(0.0, 2.0, 6.0, 9.0, 12.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5)
Alive=c(100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 10, 10, 10, 8, 100, 10, 10, 10, 9, 7, 2, 3)
Dead=c(0, 10, 12, 10, 10,  0,  0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 9, 5)
Trial=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)

model=glm(cbind(Alive, Dead)~Time+Trial, family=binomial(link="logit"))

Call:
    glm(formula = cbind(Alive, Dead) ~ Time + Trial, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = cinctipesA)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.7008   0.0000   0.1171   0.3567   2.2157  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   3.0893     1.2559   2.460   0.0139 *  
Time         -4.0455     0.7159  -5.651 1.60e-08 ***
Trial         2.9112     0.7096   4.103 4.08e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 309.566  on 17  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  14.092  on 15  degrees of freedom
AIC: 31.203

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 9

dose.p(model, cf=1:2 p=0.5)

              Dose        SE
p = 0.5:   0.7636405 0.2927676
```

This seems okay until you take a closer look at the data:

```
coef(model)
logisticline = function(z) {eta = 3.089321 + (-4.045518+2.911239) * z; 1 / (1 + exp(-eta))}
x = seq(0,12, 0.01)
lines(x, logisticline(x), new = TRUE)
abline(0.5, 0)
```

[image]

From this plot, it's clear that the point where %50 of individuals are dead is not at `Time=0.76`.

Why is there a problem calculating LT50 with these particular data?

Comment: `fitted(model)` shows that the zero values are all in trial 1 so if you are willing to eliminate that (e.g. use the argument `subset  = Trial != 1`), then you can avoid the perfect separation which is presumably causing the problem.

Comment: If Trial is a significant predictor in the model, is it okay to remove it? Doing so does fix the problem of perfect separation and provides an LT50 that matches the plot however.

Comment: If you use the `subset = Trial != 1` arg and also make `Trial` a factor (which it should have been all along) then Trial is not significant.

Comment: This still doesn't give a LT50 that agrees with the plot. Using the model: `model=glm(cbind(Alive, Dead)~Time+Trial, family=binomial(link="logit"), subset = Trial != 1)` the dose.p value is: `2.006084`

Comment: You forgot the factor(Trial) part:   `model=glm(cbind(Alive, Dead)~Time+factor(Trial), family=binomial(link="logit"), subset = Trial != 1)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139287/discussion-between-hamilthj-and-g-grothendieck).

Answer (score 0):

You have removed 'Trial' in your fitted line. If 'Trial' is included in the model, then you need three curves. If this is your intention than you should refer to p191 'Vernables and Ripley 2002 - Modern Applied Statistics with S' where 'dose.p' is described for a two-factor analysis. However, since you have so few data points, I doubt you can/should fit three curves.

Ignoring 'Trial' in the model will give you a LT50 that makes sense.

```
model=glm(cbind(Alive, Dead)~Time, family=binomial(link="logit"))

dose.p(md1, cf=1:2, p=0.5)
```

> ```
>        Dose        SE
> ```
>
> p = 0.5: 2.58857 0.1423731